# Quicksort with a DoubleLinkedList?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, quicksort

I have a homework assignment to create a quicksort method (and associated methods) using a DoubleLinkedList. I am having trouble because the method stub provided for quicksort only takes one parameter, the list itself. All of the examples I've seen use low and high values in the recursion for quicksort.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// code removed for academic integrity reasons, will be replaced after Spring, 2019
```

This seems to work but I'm not sure how to store the values on the call stack and concatenate them back onto the list, so I can't really test it. I basically am just putting in a list and sorting it into subsequently smaller lists that disappear into the aether.

EDIT: Methods called in the DLL class:

- size() - returns an integer representing the number of nodes in the list.
- removeLast() - removes the last node in the DLL (the tail) and returns the value of its element.
- removeFirst() - removes the first node in the DLL (the head) and returns the value of its element.
- add() - adds a new node to the end of the DLL with the designated element.
- isEmpty() - returns true if the list has no nodes (size == 0).

Comment: *I am having trouble because the method stub provided for quicksort only takes one parameter, the list itself.* Delegate to another method that takes high and low values...

Comment: In order to really help and run your code as part of a [mcve], youll have to add your list classes. Otherwise, if the problem is the indicies, that's solved by method overloading... The true problem will be iterating the list to get to the correct node. Plus, confused how `list.removeLast()` works since there's no "last element" in a double linked list

Comment: @cricket_007 you mean my whole DoubleLinkedList class? That's 550 lines of code.. I'm not sure I know what you mean. We don't use indices for our DLLs (except to keep track in the ListIterator). The way we wrote our DLL it has a head and tail, and does not loop back on itself, so the removeLast() method removes the tail, basically.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that the head and reach the tail in one hop... But yes, if someone were to offer a solution, it's a good idea to test beforehand. Thus, we'd need to have your list definitions

Comment: @cricket_007 I've edited the original post with definitions for the methods I've included.

Comment: Perhaps you should respond to the idea in the first comment? It seems reasonable to me, so what issues are you having when trying?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I just needed to add a way to add the sorted values back into the list. I'll update the original post with the solution after the due date has passed (this Friday). @cricket_007 I thought about that, but that didn't make sense to have a quicksort that called a second quicksort that worked differently from the original intent. Further, the instructor specifically told us to use the remove methods to make two lower and upper lists etc. The solution ended up being quite simple this way :)

Comment: Feel free to post a solution below as an answer, rather than above in the "question"

Comment: @cricket_007 answer posted, if you're interested :) I had to wait a bit longer because they extended the due date.